# Is there any Interdependent Collections Modifications Management Framework?

Tags: c#, collections

Last day I ended up thinking about some collections interdependence.

I cannot put a better label, name, title, or whatever suggesting this situation... so feel free to suggest anything better than my cheap labeling, that is " Interdependent Collections Modifications Management".

Long story short, the example below.

First, let's consider a couple of classes:

```
public class DummyItem
{
    public DummyItem(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}

// A kind of repository of DummyItems
public class BusinessClassProvider
{
    public BusinessClassProvider()
    {
        this.Collection = new List<DummyItem>();
    }

    public IList<DummyItem> DummyItems{ get; private set; }
}

public class BusinessClassConsumer
{
    public BusinessClassConsumer()
    {
        this.Collection = new Collection<DummyItem>();
    }

    public ICollection<DummyItem> DummItems{ get; private set; }
}
```

Now let's say that BusinessClassProvider.Collection is populated via some processes, user inputs, etc.

The BusinessClassConsumer Collection is something selected from BusinessClassProvider Collection by let's say also some user inputs or any other way.

Now if I remove or add a DummyItem from the BusinessClassProvider Collection I need to create Additional Nethods to wrap  or eventually if they are some events supported to notify the others of what have been changed and remove accordingly the related other Collections (e.g. BusinessClassConsumer one) to also remove this item. 
Basically it means a lot of boilerplate code and a lot of stuff to handle manually.

Of course, we could go with another strategy using IEnumerable as BusinessClassConsumer Collection but it does not provide the same options about indexing for instance, furthermore it forces to iterate over and over on BusinessClassProvider Collection.

I know it raises many more questions like which collection is kinda the provider and the others which consumes from.

Is there any frameworks via Attributes, or any other nasty tricks to enforce the dependency between several collections?

By the way, once again, is there anybody who knows how to label correctly this sort of situation?

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to be notified when a collection change (item added, removed or the whole collection refreshed) you might want to use an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).
It's used mostly in WPF to notify the UI when a collection of item has changed and needs to be refreshed.

If your need is a producer/consumer collection, you might want to look for a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
It's a thread safe collection that do all the producer/consumer things for you.

Comment: I would rather say that notification is only a part of job. What I am looking for is something that would automatically delete a collection item when reflecting the deletion in another collection.

About the notification side there is not only ObservableCollection that can do job of being notified, any proper implementation of the IBindingList can also work (and INotifyPropertyChanged for eventuelly being notify about how a item has been changed).

Producer/Consumer concurrency strategy has nothing to do with the the current topic, except that I have I used the same word "Consumer".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. Quite a few actually, but ObservableCollection that come with .net are not preferred. Instead one would use [Rx-Linq](https://rx.codeplex.com/)(Reactive extension) that adds observables, Linq and schedulers together.

Comment: Note however Rx Linq can have steep learning curve for beginners.

Comment: I am aware of RX, but it seems like I would have to handle a lot of stuff manually.